# как отследить отпускание клавиши мыши? (Python)

Tags: python

к примеру я отпущу левую клавишу мыши и пропишется "hello world".
спасибо если поможете, прошу какой-то короткий код

Comment: Короткий код: import keyboard, mouse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для отслеживания отпускания клавиши мыши в Python можно воспользоваться библиотекой pynput. Вот пример кода, который отслеживает отпускание левой кнопки мыши:

```py
from pynput.mouse import Listener

def on_release(x, y, button, pressed):
    if not pressed:
        if button == Button.left:
            print('Левая кнопка мыши была отпущена')

with Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Этот код создает слушателя событий мыши и при отпускании левой кнопки мыши выводит сообщение в консоль. Можно легко модифицировать этот код для отслеживания отпускания других кнопок мыши или для выполнения других действий при событии отпускания кнопки.

Не забудь установить библиотеку pynput перед запуском кода, используя команду pip install pynput.

Comment: благодарю наглядный и короткий код, спасибо большое !!!

Comment: блин одна проблемка, почему-то ничего не происходит, но если в функцию переименовать в on_click то работает.

Answer (score 0):

https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html

Попробуй эту библиотеку. Сам не пробовал, но выглядит здраво. Тебя интересует .release